# When building a website with html, and css. Is it possible to create a link to another page with Css alone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When building a website with HTML, and CSS. Is it possible to create a link to another page with CSS alone?. To be more specific, I don't want to use an anchor tag with HTML.

Comment: With javascript. CSS is a style language.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an a tag?

Answer (score 1):

No — CSS stands for 'Cascading Style Sheets', It does not provide anything other than styling. You CAN create a link without an A-tag though with Javascript, like this:

```html
// Define your 'link' element
const el = document.getElementById('not-link-element');

// Define your target URL
const href = 'www.url-here.com';

// When your element is clicked, navigate to your target URL
el.addEventListener('click', function () {                  
  window.location.href = href;  
});
```

That said, I highly, highly discourage it and can't see any use case where you'd have a clickable link but wouldn't use an A-tag, so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, as CSS is a styling language. To write content you would need HTML, a markup language.

If you don't want to use HTML directly, you could use JavaScript, a high-level programming language that can manipulate the DOM (Document Object Model). One way to do it is using the `write()` method, which you can reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp.

Answer (score -2):

For do that I recommend to you use an  tag

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

Then you could add to it some css style using a class for example

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" class="yourCssClass">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

Then you could define the style at the css class.

```
.yourCssClass {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. This answer seems to be missing the point of the question a bit. OP explicitly asked whether it's possible to create links without HTML anchor elements/tags.